# how to make scala parser fail

Tags: scala

so I have something like this:

```
class MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
    var m = new HashMap[String,String]
    def store = ("var" ~> ident "=") ~ ident ^^ {
        case k ~ v => m += k -> v
    }
    def stored_val = ident ^^ {
        case k => m(k)
    }
}
```

And my problem is that what I really want to do is have the parser stored_val fail so that other parsers have the chance to match the input. But what happens now is that the map throws when it can't find the value.

I tried implementing stored_val like this:

```
def stored_val = ident => {
    case k => if (m.contains(k)) m(k) else failure("identifier not found")
}
```

But the problem with that is failure returns Parser[Nothing] which is a different type than String.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and want to explicitly fail the parser. How is failure supposed to be used if its Nothing-type is not compatible with anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check the content of the characters beyond regex, you might want to check out [`StandardTokenParser`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/syntactical/StandardTokenParsers.html). In particular,

```
def elem (kind: String, p: (Elem) ⇒ Boolean) : Parser[Elem]
```

> A parser matching input elements that satisfy a given predicate
>   `elem(kind, p)` succeeds if the input starts with an element `e'` for which `p(e)` is true.

**Edit**:
For examples of Standard Token Parser, check out Jim McBeath's article on [Scala Parser Combinators](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/09/scala-parser-combinators.html). I made a quick modification to the first example to demonstrate `elem`. It's a simple parser that only takes sum of odd numbers:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

trait Expression
case class EConstant(value: Int) extends Expression
case class EAdd(lhs: Expression, rhs: Expression) extends Expression

object ExpressionParser extends StandardTokenParsers {
  lexical.delimiters ++= List("+")

  def oddValue = elem("odd", { x => x.toString.toInt % 2 == 1 }) ^^ {
    x => EConstant(x.toString.toInt) }
  def value = numericLit ^^ { x => EConstant(x.toInt) }

  def sum = oddValue ~ "+" ~ oddValue ^^ { case left ~ "+" ~ right =>
          EAdd(left, right) }

  def expr = ( sum | value )

  def parse(s:String) = {
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(s)
    phrase(expr)(tokens)
  }

  def apply(s:String): Expression = parse(s) match {
    case Success(tree, _) => tree
    case e: NoSuccess =>
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad syntax: "+s)
  }
}
```

Save the above as `ExpressionParser.scala` and load it into REPL as follows:

```
scala> :l ExpressionParser.scala     
Loading ExpressionParser.scala...
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
defined trait Expression
defined class EConstant
defined class EAdd
defined module ExpressionParser

scala> ExpressionParser("2 + 2")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad syntax: 2 + 2
    at ExpressionParser$.apply(<console>:42)
    at .<init>(<console>:24)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
    at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Interpreter.scala:988)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Interpreter.scala:988)
    at scala.util.con...
scala> ExpressionParser("1 + 1")
res3: Expression = EAdd(EConstant(1),EConstant(1))
```

Comment: @Kevin said - I did see that method, but I wasn't exactly sure how to use it. Can you provide a small example? Essentially I want my predicate to return true if m.contains(k) == true.

Comment: I did see that method, but I wasn't exactly sure how to use it. Can you provide a small example? Essentially I want my predicate to return true if m.contains(k) == true.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `^?` combinator which accepts a partial function ([Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers%24Parser)):

```
def stored_val: Parser[String] = ident ^? {
    case k if m.contains(k) => m(k)
}
```

I pushed a [full example](https://github.com/AlexanderDaniel/parser-combinators/blob/master/src/main/scala/lachdrache/stackoverflow/MyParser.scala) with [tests](https://github.com/AlexanderDaniel/parser-combinators/blob/master/src/test/scala/lachdrache/stackoverflow/MyParserSuite.scala) to Github.