# How can I make my parser fail gracefully if an exception is thrown?

Tags: scala, parsing, exception, parser-combinators

Here is my attempt at writing a small parser for *positive* `Int`s:

```scala
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object PositiveIntParser extends RegexParsers {

  private def positiveInt: Parser[Int] = """0*[1-9]\d*""".r ^^ { _.toInt }

  def apply(input: String): Option[Int] = parseAll(positiveInt, input) match {
    case Success(result, _) => Some(result)
    case _ => None
  }

}
```

The problem is that, if the input string is too long, `toInt` throws an `NumberFormatException`, which makes my parser blow up:

```scala
scala> :load PositiveIntParser.scala
Loading PositiveIntParser.scala...
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
defined object PositiveIntParser

scala> PositiveIntParser("12")
res0: Option[Int] = Some(12)

scala> PositiveIntParser("-12")
res1: Option[Int] = None

scala> PositiveIntParser("123123123123123123")
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123123123123123123"
  at ...
```

Instead, I would like my `positiveInt` parser to fail gracefully (by returning a `Failure`) when `toInt` throws an exception. How can I do that?

An easy fix that comes to mind consists in limiting the length of the strings accepted by my regex, but that's unsatisfactory.

I'm guessing that a parser combinator for this use case is already provided by the `scala.util.parsing.combinator` library, but I've been unable to find one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combinator accepting a partial function (inspired by [how to make scala parser fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14983424/16673)):

```
private def positiveInt: Parser[Int] = """0*[1-9]\d*""".r ^? {
  case x if Try(x.toInt).isSuccess => x.toInt
}
```

If you want to avoid the double conversion, you can create an extractor to perform the matching and conversion:

```
object ParsedInt {
  def unapply(str: String): Option[Int] = Try(str.toInt).toOption
}

private def positiveInt: Parser[Int] = """0*[1-9]\d*""".r ^? { case ParsedInt(x) => x }
```

It is also possible to move the positiveness test into the case condition, which I find more readable than a bit intricate regex:

```
private def positiveInt: Parser[Int] = """\d+""".r ^? { case ParsedInt(x) if x > 0 => x }
```

As per your comment the extraction can also be performed in a separate `^^` step, as follows:

```
private def positiveInt: Parser[Int] = """\d+""".r ^^
  { str => Try(str.toInt)} ^? { case util.Success(x) if x > 0 => x }
```

Comment: Thanks. `^?` is the combinator I was missing. In the end, I went for: `private def positiveInt: Parser[Int] = {
    def safeToInt(str: String) = Try(str.toInt)
    """\d+""".r ^^ safeToInt ^? { case scala.util.Success(result) if result > 0 => result }
  }`.

Comment: You can use `Function.unlift` to convert a function returning `Option` to a `PartialFunction`. E.g., `"""0*[1-9]\d*""".r ^? Function.unlift { x => Try(x.toInt).toOption }`

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the call to `parseAll` with `Try()`?

```
Try(parseAll(positiveInt, input))
```

`scala.util.Try`'s `apply` method will wrap any exception in  `Failure[T]`, and then you can even use `.toOption` to convert any `Failure` to a `None`.

```
Try(parseAll(positiveInt, input)).toOption
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather fix the problem at the source: `positiveInt`.